# Ongoing crash in Android Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Whenever i start my application, it keep crashing.
As i had some similiar problems in the past with the RelativeLayout, i'd guess the problem is related to this.
I created the layout with the Graphical Interface.

Neither the java application, nor the layout returns any errors or important warnings.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.XXX.mcgneussapp2;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ProgressBar Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pB1);
        final TextView loadtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        final ImageView imgFavorite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        final ImageView imgFavorite2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        final ImageView imgFavorite3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

        WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);  
        engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
        {  
            @Override  
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  
            {  
              return false;  
            }  

            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                loadtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Pbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                loadtext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });          


        imgFavorite.setClickable(true);
        imgFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  //favoriten
            {
                WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);  
                engine.loadUrl("https://www.free-way.me/mcgapp/recommend.php");
                imgFavorite3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgFavorite2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        imgFavorite2.setClickable(true);
        imgFavorite2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  //weiter
            {
                WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);  
                engine.loadUrl("https://www.free-way.me/mcgapp/index.php?siteid=1&nohead");
                imgFavorite3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgFavorite2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        imgFavorite3.setClickable(true);
        imgFavorite3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) //zurück
            {
                WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);  
                engine.loadUrl("https://www.free-way.me/mcgapp/index.php?nohead");
                imgFavorite3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgFavorite2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        engine.loadUrl("https://www.free-way.me/mcgapp/index.php?nohead");  
        imgFavorite3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/bottom_bar" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_myplaces" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/pB1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Bitte warten"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pB1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_engine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**LogCat Dump**

```
 > 02-12 11:45:32.795: D/AndroidRuntime(309): Shutting down VM 02-12
    > 11:45:32.795: W/dalvikvm(309): threadid=1: thread exiting with
    > uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 02-12 11:45:32.805:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-12 11:45:32.805:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
    > activity
    > ComponentInfo{com.XXX.mcgneussapp2/com.XXX.mcgneussapp2.MainActivity}:
    > java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView 02-12
    > 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 02-12
    > 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at
    > android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-12
    > 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at
    > android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 02-12 11:45:32.805:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 02-12
    > 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at
    > java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-12
    > 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at
    > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 02-12 11:45:32.805:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 02-12
    > 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at
    > dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-12 11:45:32.805:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
    > android.widget.ImageView 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):
    >   at
    > com.XXX.mcgneussapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    > 02-12 11:45:32.805: E/AndroidRuntime(309):    ... 11 more 02-12
    > 11:45:35.784: I/Process(309): Sending signal. PID: 309 SIG: 9 02-12
    > 11:46:26.815: D/AndroidRuntime(343): Shutting down VM 02-12
    > 11:46:26.815: W/dalvikvm(343): threadid=1: thread exiting with
    > uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800) 02-12 11:46:26.825:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 02-12 11:46:26.825:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
    > activity
    > ComponentInfo{com.XXX.mcgneussapp2/com.XXX.mcgneussapp2.MainActivity}:
    > java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView 02-12
    > 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 02-12
    > 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at
    > android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-12
    > 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at
    > android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 02-12 11:46:26.825:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 02-12
    > 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at
    > java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-12
    > 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at
    > java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 02-12 11:46:26.825:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 02-12
    > 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at
    > dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 02-12 11:46:26.825:
    > E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
    > android.widget.ImageView 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):
    >   at
    > com.XXX.mcgneussapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    at
    > android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    > 02-12 11:46:26.825: E/AndroidRuntime(343):    ... 11 more
```

//edit:
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.XXX.mcgneussapp2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.XXX.mcgneussapp2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you indicate line 24 in MainActivity.java. that's where the error occurs.

Comment: Please add your AndroidManifest.xml file. It looks like there your Activity is not declared correctly.

Comment: it seem you have a `ClassCastException` when initializing your `TextView` and your wml seems to be fine.. 
did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Your code worked fine here. Try cleaning your project and rebuild, as A.A suggested.

Comment: @Minsky I added the Manifest.xml. Cleaning the project made it work again :o Is there any explanaiton why and when this problem occurs? I even started a new project and copied only the important stuff over and it still didn't work...

Comment: @James I am unsure, why this happens. Somehow Eclipse or the Android PlugIn does not recognize all changes in the xml-files, and does not regenerate the ressource file (R.java) automatically. At runtime a newly added view (via its id) is not found then. This happens despite the editor finds the id in the java file. I often run in this problem and do clean and rebuild often, after XML changes (color, dimens, drawables, style-files too)

Comment: @Minsky Thanks for the information. Would you be so kind and put your answer that solved the problem in a seperate post so i can mark the problem as solved and give you the karma you deserve? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked fine here. Try cleaning your project and rebuild, as A.A suggested in the comments.